# AWS API Gateway throws 502 error for web applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a lambda function at the API gateway level to communicate with the Application Load Balancer. The lambda function is working for when making the REST API request. But the same function is not working when loading the web application. It throws 502 error. When I checked in the cloud watch log, the API gateway throws the  "Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response" error. But I have set the proxy response properly.

Can anyone please let me know the solution for this issue?

```
var response = {
    'statusCode': res.statusCode,
    'headers': res.headers,
    'body': data,
    'isBase64Encoded': true
};
callback(null, response);
```

Comment: `data` assigned to body is string? If not you need to stringify it.

Comment: You may also need to configure your vpc to allow lambda to interact with the LB. See here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html